# OpenCV C++ give architecture arm64 error in Macbook M1 chip

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, arm64, apple-m1

I built OpenCV-4.5.2 in Macbook M1 followed this tutorial: https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1. It works fine in Python but when I use in C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("avatar.jpeg");
    return 0;
}
```

It give an error in cv::Mat

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "cv::Mat::~Mat()", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
  "cv::imread(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [imgproc] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/imgproc.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/imgproc.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [imgproc] Error 2
```

After hours, I can't find what's wrong with it. Can anybody help me? Thank you!

P/S: as additional, this is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)
project(imgproc)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

# Set the location of the OpenCV directory
set(OpenCV_DIR "/usr/local/include/opencv4")
# Find OpenCV library
find_package( OpenCV 4 REQUIRED )
# Add header file
include_directories(include ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )


add_executable(imgproc main.cpp)
```

Comment: Have you added the link arguments to the compiler command?

You'll need something like `g++ main.cpp $(pkg-config --libs opencv)`

Comment: It seems no use in this case, the error still appears

Comment: In my case, I use also M1 Mac. The OpenCV path was `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.2_1/include/opencv4/`. Therefore, I utilized a command: `g++ $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4) -std=c++11  main.cpp -o main.o`. However, not using `cv::mat`, main function has just `return 0` so that the compile was successful. By the way, if the main function include `cv::mat`, it throw me the same compile error. So, I've concluded that it is because M1 Mac Architecture doesn't support OpenCV codes yet. I'm also finding the solution still.

Answer (score 2):

I found that replace these include:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
```

with:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

Then everything worked!

Answer (score 2):

After some exploration I finally solved the problem. To user the openCV library on M1 Mac, you need to include `-I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.5/include/opencv4/ -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.5.5/lib/` as your g++ compile options.

Comment: Worked for me, with minor update for opencv version. I did  `-I$(brew --prefix opencv)/include/opencv4 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_highgui -L$(brew --prefix opencv)/lib` and this will adapt as the version changes (presumably until opencv5 ..!)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested OpenCV in macOS successfully, refer to:
https://medium.com/@mfkhao2009/set-up-opencv-development-enrioment-875aa69bd403

You should link the library to the target imgproc by adding this code to `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable(imgproc main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(imgproc PUBLIC ${OpenCV_LIBS} )

// or in old cmake version: 
add_executable(imgproc main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(imgproc ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

Answer (score -1):

I've been dealing with the same issue. I kept getting the linker error (Undefined symbols for architecture arm64...). FYI I installed via homebrew on my M1 mac, and developing with CLion.

What solved it was adding this to specifiy X86_64 in cmake:

```
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64)
```

My full `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.9)
set(CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES x86_64)
project(opencvtest)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(opencvtest main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(opencvtest ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```