# opencv.hpp file not found vscode Mac M1

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, apple-m1

I have been trying to set up opencv on my M1 chip Mac in Vscode, I used home-brew and followed all of the necessary steps to install it on my Mac. I created a vscode project and included it in the c_cpp_properties.json and task.json files. When I wrote up a simple test program I built the program using g++ but the build failed and threw an error stating:

> fatal error: 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found

I tried a bunch of different ways of including the libraries but there is still a squiggled line in front of #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp> in my program which wasn't there prior to building the program. Intellisense provides me with suggestions in the program and everything. I went through the few existing questions on stack overflow and none of them had a working solution for me.

I tried a bunch of different solutions that I found online and in and around the forums but nothing seems to be working
These are my c_cpp_properties.json and task.json files:
Task.json:

```
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I",
                "/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv2",
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++"
        }
    ]
}
```

c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv2",
                "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64",
            "configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

the code for my sample code is as follows:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std; 


/////////////////  Images  //////////////////////

int main() {

    string path = "/Users/brettmylek/Desktop/OpenCV/Img/TestImg.jpg";
    Mat img = imread(path);
    imshow("Image", img);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

it is simply there to open an image to test whether or not the install was successful so I could go on developing my actual project.

Comment: You're keeping opencv on your Desktop?

Comment: I've never used opencv, but my expectation of a C++ project once third party libraries are involved is to use cmake.

Comment: if you are sure you installed opencv properly, then you are getting the error because of the linking issue. you should link opencv libraries to your tool

Comment: I would guess the include path for opencv2 is one directory too deep.   Which @Milan_Š. points out below.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems and just solved it. For reference, I had installed OpenCV via homebrew, and VSCode Extensions `C/C++` and `C/C++ Extension Pack` (both written by Microsoft). I have a Mac M1 and had been using Xcode before, so perhaps that had installed something compiler-related already.

Anyway, to check the path where OpenCV is installed, try `brew --prefix opencv` and it should give something like `/opt/homebrew/opt/opencv`.

This file is a symlink into homebrew's Cellar - so that if you change versions of opencv, this file reference will remain the same. (Incidentally, you can see the actual place on disk by typing `readlink -f $(brew --prefix opencv)` and you should get something like `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_1`).

The opencv2 folder with the header files in that you need to reference is two directories down from this - for me at the time of writing it is in `/include/opencv4`.

A key aha moment was that the Visual Studio settings file `.vscode/c_cpp_properties.json` file is used purely by VSCode for autocompletion, so in there I added the includePath `/opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/include/opencv4`.

Then in the `tasks.json` file, I had to add to the `"args"` section:

```
"-I$(brew --prefix opencv)/include/opencv4",
"-L$(brew --prefix opencv)/lib",
"-lopencv_core",
"-lopencv_imgcodecs",
"-lopencv_highgui",
```

I did adapt this from [another StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71722172/4991483), so thanks to Jeffrey Yu for that.

Just to explain that the `$(brew --prefix opencv)` runs a mini script inside the command line that runs the compiler, so you end up with the full path to the brew folders.

So my tasks.json file looks like this:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-I$(brew --prefix opencv)/include/opencv4",
                "-L$(brew --prefix opencv)/lib",
                "-lopencv_core",
                "-lopencv_imgcodecs",
                "-lopencv_highgui",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

And my c_cpp_properties.json looks like this:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/opt/homebrew/opt/opencv/include/opencv4"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "macFrameworkPath": [
                "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/clang",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "macos-clang-arm64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

And for reference my test program looks like this:

```
// opencv-test.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat image = imread("my-image.jpg", IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    if (image.empty()) {
        cout << "Not a valid image file" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    namedWindow("Simple Demo", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Simple Demo", image);

    waitKey(0);
    destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

As a more bullet-proof method that includes all the OpenCV libraries available, you could instead of the tasks.json adjustments above add:

```
"`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`",
```

This works because `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4` (try it without the back-ticks on the command line) generates all the include and link information you need for the entire package.

Answer (score 0):

I'll start with `c_cpp_properties.json` more precisely the `includePath` element. This element is only and only for IntelliSense. It has no other use whatsoever. This should answer why IntelliSense is working.

If you then look into `tasks.json` one thing that caught my eye is this:

```
"args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
 -->        "-I",
 -->        "/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv2",
 -->        "/usr/local/include/opencv4"
],
```

This most likely doesn't work the way you think it does. What you want instead is:

```
"args": [
            "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "-I/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv2",
            "-I/usr/local/include/opencv4"
],
```

EDIT: You might have to link against built opencv libraries (last time I checked it's not a header-only library)

<strike>EDIT2: Also are you sure about this path: `/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv2`"</strike>

Last time I checked there is no `/Users` on Linux

EDIT3: I've checked their github. If the error persists it's most likely a wrong include path i.e. instead of

`"-I/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include/opencv2"`

Maybe it should be (based on their github) this:

`"-I/Users/user/Desktop/OpenCV/opencv/include"`